# Weird behavior of su command

Tags: linux, bash, bashrc, su, eval

Everytime I run `su` command on this box, I constantly see the weird messages below. Switching user do eventually continue, but why are these messages showing?

```
<Server>:~ # su -
-bash: eval: line 26: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: eval: line 27: syntax error: unexpected end of file
-bash: eval: line 26: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: eval: line 27: syntax error: unexpected end of file

<Server>:~ # cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 4

<Server>:~ # uname -r
3.0.101-108.84-default
```

---

Yes I did looked into the "." files of root but I cannot see any weird content in those. It is also happening on all users when i try to su.. not just in root.

It seems this is a new upgrade and unfortunately i cannot tell if it were able to run su successfully in the past.

```
kernel-default-3.0.101-108.84.1               Tue Mar 19 04:25:06 2019
kernel-default-base-3.0.101-108.84.1          Tue Mar 19 04:24:33 2019
kernel-default-devel-3.0.101-108.84.1         Tue Mar 19 04:24:28 2019

<Server>:~ # cat .bashrc
export TMOUT=900 # 900 s = 15 min
umask 077
<Server>:~ # cat .bash_profile
umask 077
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/quest/bin
```

Comment: Do you have an unmatched `"` in root's `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file?

Comment: From the error, it looks like one of the shell startup files is running `eval` on something that produces broken shell syntax. As @Kusalananda said, check root's startup files, but the error probably isn't directly in one of them, but in something one of them runs.

Comment: "Everytime"... how long? Is this a new install, or have you run `su` successfully in the past?

Comment: If the root profile files don't have anything odd, I'd consider `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`

Comment: I did compared all those mentioned directories/files with a working box, but nothing is different. Although I'm suspecting there is something wrong with /etc/pam.d/su or /etc/pam.d/su-l. Do anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `"` in one of the entries in  `/etc/sysconfig/proxy`.

```
for sys in /etc/sysconfig/windowmanager \
           /etc/sysconfig/mail          \
           /etc/sysconfig/proxy         \
           /etc/sysconfig/console       \
           /etc/sysconfig/news
do
    test -s $sys || continue
    while read line ; do
        case "$line" in
        \#*|"") continue ;;
        esac
        eval val=${line#*=}
```

Line 24 of `/etc/profile.d/profile.sh` is `eval val=${line#*=}`. It basically reads all of the config file above and `/etc/sysconfig/proxy` turns out to be the suspect.